# Excel VBA - Do loop work for some but not for all

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to highlight certain cells based on it's column 4 values.

Basically, If column 4 value is negative, then we search through the column 4 from the beginning and if there is positive match (That is positive of the column 4 value and then matching the respective column 3 and 6 values) then highlight all those together.

Additionally, once paired and highlighted, it should not be picked again in the middle loop therefore another condition added there.

This code is doing my job to an extent. But in between it misses some negative values that can match against the positives. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim rownumber As Integer
Dim ColumnC, ColumnF, ColumnC1, ColumnF1 As String
Dim ColumnD, ColumnD1 As Integer
Dim subrownumber As Integer
Dim Condition As Boolean

rownumber = 1

Do
ColumnD = Cells(rownumber, 4).Value
ColumnC = Cells(rownumber, 3).Value
ColumnF = Cells(rownumber, 6).Value
Condition = False

If (ColumnD < 0) Then
    subrownumber = 1
    Do
    ColumnD1 = Cells(subrownumber, 4).Value
    ColumnC1 = Cells(subrownumber, 3).Value
    ColumnF1 = Cells(subrownumber, 6).Value
            If (ColumnD1 = ColumnD * -1 And ColumnF1 = ColumnF And ColumnC1 = ColumnC) And _
              Cells(subrownumber, 4).Interior.ColorIndex <> 37 Then

                Cells(subrownumber, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                Cells(subrownumber, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                Cells(subrownumber, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                Cells(rownumber, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                Cells(rownumber, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                Cells(rownumber, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                Condition = True
            End If
    subrownumber = subrownumber + 1
    Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(subrownumber, 4)) Or Condition = True
End If
rownumber = rownumber + 1
Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(rownumber, 4))
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm struggling to follow the logic of this code - but can't help thinking that you might be able to use conditional formatting for this instead...

Comment: It is bit difficult to use conditional formatting.

This requirement is very specific (sometimes everyone feels that way)

But as explained in the question I try to match positive and negative values. And to avoid duplicate Once highlighted we avoid that on. Both positive and negative numbers are in the same column.

Comment: Perhaps you can show us an example of what goes right, and what goes wrong. I'm struggling to visualize your problem.

Comment: Can you give an example of values (say three rows C, D and F) and show what goes wrong in it? You can post those values textually without need to upload a worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally get there.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim rownumber As Integer
Dim ColumnC, ColumnF, ColumnC1, ColumnF1 As String
Dim ColumnD, ColumnD1 As Single
Dim subrownumber As Integer
Dim Condition As Boolean
rownumber = 1
Do
    ColumnD = Cells(rownumber, 4).Value
    ColumnC = Cells(rownumber, 3).Value
    ColumnF = Cells(rownumber, 6).Value
    Condition = False

If (ColumnD < 0) Then
    subrownumber = 1
    Do
        ColumnD1 = Cells(subrownumber, 4).Value
        ColumnC1 = Cells(subrownumber, 3).Value
        ColumnF1 = Cells(subrownumber, 6).Value
            If (ColumnD1 = ColumnD * -1 And ColumnF1 = ColumnF And ColumnC1 = ColumnC) And _
             Cells(subrownumber, 4).Interior.ColorIndex <> 37 And _
             Cells(rownumber, 4).Interior.ColorIndex <> 37 Then
                Cells(subrownumber, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                Cells(subrownumber, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                Cells(subrownumber, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                Cells(rownumber, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                Cells(rownumber, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                Cells(rownumber, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                Condition = True
            End If
    subrownumber = subrownumber + 1
    Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(subrownumber, 4)) Or Condition = True
End If
rownumber = rownumber + 1
Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(rownumber, 4))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is rather tricky code to follow especially without the sample data, but from what I think you're saying it should do as you want it to. You'd almost have to go through manually to see what matches you're expecting and in what order and then step through your routine to see whether it matches as you think it should.

I can't help thinking you'd be better off creating two lists: one with the negatives and the other with the positives and then just pair match one with the other. The code below does that. When I first wrote it, I thought you were saying in your post that you wanted to ignore duplicates, so this code does. If that isn't what you want to do then some adjustments will be needed.

You could use any lists or arrays but I've gone for a collection because the key can be a concat of your three cell values and therefore a quick look-up.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim posData As New Collection
Dim negData As New Collection
Dim key As String
Dim r As Long
Dim v As Variant

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

On Error Resume Next
For r = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    key = ws.Cells(r, 3).Text & " " & _
          CStr(Abs(ws.Cells(r, 4).Value2)) & " " & _
          ws.Cells(r, 6).Text
    If ws.Cells(r, 4).Value2 < 0 Then
        negData.Add r, key
    Else
        posData.Add r, key
    End If
Next

For Each v In negData
    key = ws.Cells(v, 3).Text & " " & _
          CStr(Abs(ws.Cells(v, 4).Value2)) & " " & _
          ws.Cells(v, 6).Text
    Err.Clear
    r = posData(key)
    If Err = 0 Then
        Set rng = Union(ws.Cells(v, 3), ws.Cells(v, 4), ws.Cells(v, 6), _
                        ws.Cells(r, 3), ws.Cells(r, 4), ws.Cells(r, 6))
        rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    End If
Next
```

**Update: Code that includes duplicates**

Below is some code that will do what you're asking. You mentioned that you were new to lists and arrays so I've written a solution that includes both for you to learn from.

Important: I've used a `Dictionary` class which is useful for storing lists of data. In your Visual Basic Editor you will need to go to Tools -> References and select `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` in order to have access to this class.

The way I attacked this was to have a `Dictionary` of unique values (Dcol, Ccol and Fcol) and within each `Item` another `Dictionary` containing all the duplicate values. For each new row, the code checks whether there's an unpaired reciprocal value already in the `Dictionary`. If there is, then it pairs up the two and paints the cells; if not it adds the values to the dictionary and moves on.

Where this might suit your needs better is that it only loops through the worksheet once whereas yours checks the whole worksheet for each and every row ... 10 x 10 is fine but 10,000 x 10,000 would have a time issue for the user.

Enjoy!

```
Public Sub MatchMaker()

    Const SEP As String = "|"

    Dim singlesClub As Dictionary
    Dim duplicateSinglies As Dictionary
    Dim aMatchForMe(1) As String

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rowNum As Long
    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim cText As String
    Dim dVal As Integer
    Dim fText As String

    ' Initialise the objects.
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set singlesClub = New Dictionary
    Set duplicateSinglies = New Dictionary

    ' Define the loop parameters.
    startRow = IIf(Len(ws.Cells(1, "D").Text) > 0, 1, ws.Cells(1, "D").End(xlDown).Row)
    endRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through the worksheet.
    For rowNum = startRow To endRow

        ' Check the row is valid.
        If Len(ws.Cells(rowNum, "C").Text) > 0 And _
           Len(ws.Cells(rowNum, "D").Text) > 0 And _
           Len(ws.Cells(rowNum, "F").Text) > 0 And _
           IsNumeric(ws.Cells(rowNum, "D")) Then

            ' Create the key name - used to identify our dictionary items,
            ' and assign to the key array.
            cText = ws.Cells(rowNum, "C").Text
            dVal = ws.Cells(rowNum, "D").Value2
            fText = ws.Cells(rowNum, "F").Text

            ' Array index: 0=this key, 1=reciprocal "D" value key.
            aMatchForMe(0) = CStr(dVal) & SEP & cText & SEP & fText
            aMatchForMe(1) = CStr(dVal * -1) & SEP & cText & SEP & fText

            ' Define the range of this row
            Set rng = Union(ws.Cells(rowNum, "C"), _
                               ws.Cells(rowNum, "D"), _
                               ws.Cells(rowNum, "F"))


            ' Check to see if the reciprocal key exists in the unpaired dictionary.
            ' If it does, then we have at least one match.
            ' If it doesn't then we must add this key to the unpaired dictionary.

            If singlesClub.Exists(aMatchForMe(1)) Then

                ' Take the first of the duplicate values and acquire its range
                Set duplicateSinglies = singlesClub(aMatchForMe(1))

                ' Fill the cells of both pairs.
                Set rng = Union(duplicateSinglies.Items(0), rng)
                rng.Interior.ColorIndex = (rowNum Mod 17) + 2

                ' Remove the value from the unpaired dictionary.
                duplicateSinglies.Remove (duplicateSinglies.Keys(0))
                If duplicateSinglies.Count = 0 Then singlesClub.Remove (aMatchForMe(1))

            Else

                ' Add this value to the unpaired list.
                If singlesClub.Exists(aMatchForMe(0)) Then
                    Set duplicateSinglies = singlesClub(aMatchForMe(0))
                    duplicateSinglies.Add rowNum, rng
                Else
                    Set duplicateSinglies = New Dictionary
                    duplicateSinglies.Add rowNum, rng
                    singlesClub.Add aMatchForMe(0), duplicateSinglies
                End If

            End If

        End If

    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: This is working almost perfect for me. Only problem is when there is a duplicate of negatives in column 4 which can be match against non-highlighted positives, this ignores those ones. For example we have -1.00 in column 4 for three consecutive times (with equal column 3 and 6) and there three 1.00 values as well. But the code only picks the first pair and ignores the other couple of pairs.

Comment: Hi. Did you get it working or do you want me to edit the code to catch duplicates?

Comment: I did it my own way as well.. If you could modify your one little bit to avoid duplication, it would be great. I am not even a beginner to arrays and lists and would love to see ur update. Only mistake on my program was variable design at the top. Thx anyway.

Comment: That's all done and available as an edit in my post ... though it's always better to 'own' your own code so well done for fixing yours.